# How to set up RTMP protocol in Ingress Nginx?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, rtmp

I have a Kubernetes cluster set up on Google Kubernetes Engine. I have a pod that hosts an RTMP application. This application requires two ports, one for HTTP and one for RTMP. I have set up an ingress Nginx load balancer. It routes the HTTP traffic correctly. I want to be able to route the RTMP traffic as well. But when I write RTMP in my YAML file. It shows it as an unknown field. I am using skaffold and Google Cloud Build to deploy.

Here is the Ingress-srv file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: stream-server-srv
              servicePort: 8000
```

What I want to be able to do is have an entry for RTMP on port 1935. That I can then use to stream love videos using RTMP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTMP is a TCP-based protocol and standard Ingress does not support TCP services.

The NGINX Ingress controller (which it looks like you are using) can [be configured to expose TCP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).

First, you'll need to make sure that you expose both the HTTP and RTMP ports in your `stream-server-srv` Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stream-server-srv
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: stream-server
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
    - name: rtmp-port
      port: 1935
      targetPort: 1935
      protocol: TCP
```

(replace default with your namespace)

You will also need to make sure that the [Service used to expose the NGINX ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud/1.23/deploy.yaml#L313) exposes port 1935 as well.  For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  - name: rtmp
    port: 1935
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1935
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Finally, you'll need to update / patch the NGINX tcp services ConfigMap:

```
kubectl patch configmap tcp-services -n ingress-nginx --patch '{"data":{"1935":"default/stream-server-srv:1935"}}'
```

(replace "default/stream-server-srv" with your namespace/servicename)